# conversion from decimal to binary in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have the following formula

```
fun foo 0 = [0] 
  | foo num = let val l =  (num mod 2)::foo(num div 2) in
           rev l
           end;
```

which is supposed to convert from decimal to binary.It has the following signature

```
val foo = fn : int -> int list
```

I am not sure where exactly I am getting things wrong as I am getting incorrect results.May someone help me figure out where I am making the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you reverse the resulting list *in every recursive step*, instead of just once at the end.

Also, you probably need to map 0 to the empty list, otherwise you'll have one 0 too many in the end.

Comment: I finally got it,I reversed after all conversions    `local
       fun convert 0 = [0]
          | convert x  = if x = 1 then [1] else      (Int.rem(x,2))::convert(x div 2)
in  
    fun foo num = rev (convert(num))
end;`

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what Andreas said. Now, the obvious way to get around this is to use a wrapper function:

```
fun f n =
let
  fun f' 0   = []
    | f' num = num mod 2 :: f' (num div 2)
in
  rev (f' n)
end
```

This works, but has the disadvantage of first building up the list, and then traversing it (the `rev` call). It also isn't tail-recursive. We can do better!

Instead of using reverse, we flip things around and use an accumulator:

```
fun g n =
let
  fun g' 0   acc = acc
    | g' num acc = g' (num div 2) (num mod 2 :: acc)
in
  g' n []
end
```

To understand the difference, let's see what happens if we run each of these on the number 4.

```
f 4 -> rev (f' 4)
    -> rev (4 mod 2 :: f' (4 div 2))
    -> rev (0 :: f' 2)
    -> rev (0 :: 2 mod 2 :: f' (2 div 2))
    -> rev (0 :: 0 :: f' 1)
    -> rev (0 :: 0 :: 1 mod 2 :: f' (1 div 2))
    -> rev (0 :: 0 :: 1 :: f' 0)
    -> rev (0 :: 0 :: 1 :: [])
    -> [1, 0, 0]

g 4 -> g' 4 []
    -> g' (4 div 2) (4 mod 2 :: [])
    -> g' 2 (0 :: [])
    -> g' (2 div 2) (2 mod 2 :: 0 :: [])
    -> g' 1 (0 :: 0 :: [])
    -> g' (1 div 2) (1 mod 2 :: 0 :: 0 :: [])
    -> g' 0 (1 :: 0 :: 0 :: [])
    -> [1, 0, 0]
```